# Recording problem in Audacity

Tags: audio-recording, audacity

In recording-mode [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/help/documentation/) doesn't accept input signals unless the 3.5 mm input-jack plug is disconnected and connected again while the PC is powered on and Audacity is running . It does not accept the input signal when the plug is constantly connected to an input on the backside of the PC.

Comment: We need more information; please help us help you by providing the make and model of your desktop PC; please obtain the model number from the serial number plate or sticker. Also, please advise which color jack your input source cable is plugged in to, and provide a screenshot of your Device toolbar https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/toolbars_overview.html by uplocating that to http://imgur.com, then add the weblink to your question. Please click [edit] to add that information to the question; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Thanks, but I think I don't find the time to do this. I'm a senior hardware-technician and I can assure you It's no hardware problem.

Comment: Problem solved, as result of a Audicity software-update, the default option for input ¨Front-microphone 0¨ was chosen. I changed this to ¨Input Line 0¨ and the problem was solved. Thanks for your support anyhow. Regards, Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely no hardware problem.
Problem solved, as result of a Audicity software-update, the default option for input ¨Front-microphone 0¨ was chosen. I changed this to ¨Input Line 0¨ and the problem was solved. Thanks for your support anyhow. Regards, Jan. –